# 青空文庫（https://www.aozora.gr.jp）における全作品のテキストデータと初版発行年の取得

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

現在私は青空文庫というページにあるデータを入力とする機械学習モデルを作ろうと考えています。
そのモデルの入力として青空文庫(https://www.aozora.gr.jp) にある作品のテキストデータとその作品の初版発行年が必要なのですが、これらのデータを抽出する方法がわからず困っています。
青空文庫には様々な作家による小説が保存されていて、ブラウザで直接個別の作品にアクセスできます。
例えば、青空文庫のトップページから以下のように「ああ華族様だよ　と私は嘘を吐くのであった」という作品のページに飛ぶとテキストデータをダウンロードでき、その末尾の底本情報に以下のように初版出版年などが書かれています。
[image: 青空文庫のトップページ]
[image: 上の写真のページであ行の作品のページに飛んだ場合]
[image: 上の写真のページからで「ああ華族様だよ と私は嘘を吐くのであった」という作品のページに飛んだ場合]
[image: 上のページからダウンロードしたテキストファイルに書かれている情報]

最初はスクレイピングでデータ抽出することを考えたのですが、githubで青空文庫のデータを一括ダウンロード(https://github.com/aozorabunko/aozorabunko) できることや野良APIであるPubserver(https://qiita.com/ksato9700/items/48fd0eba67316d58b9d6) を利用することができることも知りました。ただ、やはり青空文庫の全ての作品に対してテキストデータと初版発行年を抽出し、後で機械学習にかける入力として作品ごとのテキストデータと初版発行年の組をそれぞれ区別して保存する方法がわからずに混乱しています。
例えば、上にあげたgithubからデータをダウンロードする場合、cardsに入っている各ファイルの中にあるfilesからテキストデータと初版発行年が埋め込まれたzipファイルを全ての作品についてparseするのが良いのでしょうか?
初心者的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、アドバイスをいただけると大変助かります。

Comment: 青空文庫のテキストは、複数の出版社から出版されていても、任意の一つの初版発行日しか解りませんが、それでも構わないのでしょうか？また、それぞれとは、何と何と何を指していますか？一番質問したいのは、スクレイピングした任意のデーターのファイルへの保存方法でしょうか？青空文庫のテキストについての質問なのか、`python`でのファイルへの書き出しに付いての質問なのかがわかるように質問を書き替えると、的が絞られた回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: [公開中 作家別作品一覧拡充版:全て(CSV形式、UTF-8、zip圧縮)](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/list_person_all_extended_utf8.zip) というデータがあり、この中に「底本初版発行年1」や「底本初版発行年2」というカラムがあります。また、「テキストファイルURL」という項目がありますので、これを使って目的のテキストファイルをダウンロードすることができます。

Comment: @metropolis コメントをいただきありがとうございます。つまり、コメントをいただいたcsvを参照して全ての「テキストファイルURL」からzipファイルをダウンロードした上で、そのzipファイルをparseをしていけば目的のデータが取れるということですよね...?

Comment: はい、そうなります。ただ、ざっと見た限りですと、底本初版発行年が空欄の作品がいくつかある様です(おそらく、出版年が不明ということではないかと)。

Comment: @Чайка 青空文庫のテキストは、複数の出版社から出版されていても、任意の一つの初版発行日しか解りませんが、それでも構わないのでしょうか？　　←構わないです。また逆に底本情報の欄に初出の年月日などが書かれているなら初版発行年としてそちらを採用するようなデータ収集および保存を行いたいです

Comment: @Чайка また、それぞれとは、何と何と何を指していますか？←私自身の質問投稿の該当箇所を修正しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: @metropolis 了解しました。底本初版発行年が空欄の作品は無視して他の作品からデータを取りたいと思います。

Comment: @Чайка 一番質問したいのは、スクレイピングした任意のデーターのファイルへの保存方法でしょうか？　← 正直なところ質問を投稿した時はデータの"取り方"と"保存方法"のどちらも聞いているつもりでした。ただ、metropolisさんとのコメントのやり取りを経て"取り方"の方はなんとかわかってきたという感じです。つまり、今お聞きしたいのは、Чайкаさんのおっしゃるように、スクレイピングしたデータのファイルへの保存方法で間違い無いです。

Comment: @Чайка 青空文庫のテキストについての質問なのか、pythonでのファイルへの書き出しに付いての質問なのかがわかるように質問を書き替えると、的が絞られた回答が得られやすいと思います。←了解しました。今知りたいのは「pythonでのファイルへの書き出し」の方なので、また別に質問を投稿しようと考えているのですが、それで良いでしょうか?

Comment: @metropolis metropolisさんのやり方でデータをとると、全作品に対してダウンロードを行う場合、青空文庫のサーバーに大きな負荷をかけてしまう可能性があると私には思われます。これについてはどのように対処すべきでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

青空文庫テキストへのアクセスについては

[公開中 作家別作品一覧拡充版:全て(CSV形式、UTF-8、zip圧縮)](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/index_pages/list_person_all_extended_utf8.zip)

を元に、`GitHub`からクローンしたローカルリポジトリー内のzipファイルのURLをスクリプト内で、`URL`→ローカルファイルパス変換（"https://www.aozora.gr.jp/"をローカルリポジトリーへのパスに置換する）事でトラフィックを押さえられると思います。

また

- 圧縮ファイルの文字コードはいわゆるShift-JISなので、文字コード変換を事前にしておくと良い
- 圧縮ファイルの中身のファイル名は圧縮ファイルのファイル名と異なるので、リネームしてzipファイルと同じにしておいた方が良い

などの問題もありますので、ご注意下さい。
（この辺、プログラムから利用する側にとことん優しくないシステムになっており、プログラムから使いやすい構成になるように、もう少し口出し出来れば良かったと後悔しています）

ファイルへの書き込みは別質問にされるようですのでここでは割愛させていただきます

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私はプログラミングの経験が浅いこともあって具体的なコードはまだ書けていないのですが、とりあえず頭ではやり方を理解できました。

Answer (score 0):

GitHubのリポジトリで公開されているデータは、青空文庫ホームページのミラーなので、単にデータを抽出する目的だけを考えればどちらを元にしても同じかと思います。

ただし「全データ」を対象に取得を考えているなら、GitHubリポジトリからの取得を考えるべきです。
数件程度のピンポイントであればホームページに対してのスクレイピングでも構わないのかもしれませんが、全データを対象にリクエストを送ると相手先へのトラフィックで間違いなく負担をかけてしまいます。

Comment: Githubリポジトリからデータを取得した上で、そこに含まれるzipファイルから目的の全作品のテキストデータと初版発行年を抽出する方法がわからずに困っています...。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。了解致しました。全データを対象に取得を考えているので、Githubリポジトリからの取得を検討したいと思います。