# Pythonによる複数のurlの変換方法

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現, url

以下リンク先で行った質問内容が抽象的だったので、こちらでより具体的な質問をさせていただきたく存じます。
[公開中 作家別作品一覧拡充版:全て(CSV形式、UTF-8、zip圧縮)の「テキストファイルURL」をローカルファイルパス変換する方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51446/3060)

Python3によるコードで多数の`https://www.aozora.gr.jp/xxx`といったurlを全て`/Users/mmm/Documents/bunko_data/aozorabunko-master/xxx`という形式に変換したいのですが、どのようなコードが最も効率的に書けますか?

教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問からすれば正規表現無しの単純置換で出来そうな気がします。例:
`hoge.replace('https://www.aozora.gr.jp/', '/Users/mmm/Documents/bunko_data/aozorabunko-master/')`